# Investigate uniform convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1- \cos \sqrt{\frac{x^5}{n}}\right)\arctan \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1- \cos\sqrt{\frac{x^5}{n}}\right)\arctan \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{n}}$$
>
> For $x$ in:
>
> $1)\ E_1 = (0;1)$
>
> $2)\ E_2 = (1,+\infty)$

---

**Attempt:**

**1)** $E_1 = (0;1)$

Let $x = \frac{1}{n}, n > 1$. Then $x \in (0, 1)$.

Therefore $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\left(1- \cos \frac{1}{n^3}\right)\arctan \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \left(1 -
 \left[1-\frac{1}{n^6}\right]\right)\arctan \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{n^6}\arctan \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Since $\frac{1}{n^6}\arctan \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$ as $n \to \infty$, it follows that the leftmost series converges uniformly.

**Question:**

Is this approach correct? I feel that the choice of $x = \frac{1}{n}$ was somewhat arbitrary. How can I be sure that there is no an $x \in (0,1)$ not of the form $x = \frac{1}{n}$ for which the series non-uniformly converges (or even divergences)

**2)** $E_2 = (1,+\infty)$

Here I made the guess that the series non-uniformly convergence. Let $e^x = \sqrt{n}$. Then $x = \frac{1}{2}\ln n$, and we have the inequality:

$$\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{\ln^5 n}{32n}} \right)\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \left(1-\cos \sqrt{\frac{\ln^5 n}{32n}} \right)\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Since $\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{\ln^5 n}{32n}} \right)\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}$ as $n \to \infty$, we have that $\left(1-\cos \sqrt{\frac{\ln^5 n}{32n}} \right)\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}\neq 0$. Therefore the series non-uniformly converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part is wrong. Note for $x\in E_1$, 
$$ \sin x\le x, \arctan x\le x. $$
So for $x\in E_1$, 
$$ 0<\left(1- \cos \sqrt{\frac{x^5}{n}}\right)\arctan \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{n}}=2\sin^2\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac{x^5}{n}}\right)\arctan \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{n}}\le 2\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac{x^5}{n}}\right)^2\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{n}}\le\frac{e}{2}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$
Since $\sum\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ converges, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1- \cos \sqrt{\frac{x^5}{n}}\right)\arctan \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges uniformly.